# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, swift5

I'm passing model from A controller to B controller through pushview controller but when i am trying to access that model in controller its giving me this one error

I'm really new to this so please explain as simply as possible! Appreciate it in advance.

This code in A controller

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Dashboard", bundle: .main)
guard let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: "ScessFundTransferDetails")) as? ScessFundTransferDetails else {return}
controller.DataSuccess = SuccessDatModel
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

when I am accessing this data model in B controller it's giving me error

```
var DataSuccess: balanceInquiryModel?
```

Comment: Please could you show more code and no image ❓

Answer (score 0):

Well there can be some problems with it -

1. Check if the identifier passed to instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:) is correct.
2. Your variable "SuccessDatModel" type is not known here, but the type of the variable "DataSuccess" is "balanceInquiryModel" so may be it has different type.
   Make sure that SuccessDatModel is of type balanceInquiryModel or you may need to change the type of DataSuccess variable to match the type of SuccessDatModel.
3. It could also be that the "SuccessDatModel" is nil and you are trying to access a property of a nil object. You may want to add a check for this before you assign it to the DataSuccess variable.